# Double linked lists: swapping function doesn't always work

Tags: c, list

I have written this code and in general works good, but trying to run these particular lines in main, when we arrive to the point in which `i == 74` the elements of the list are `4 - 11 - 18 - 4 - 10 - 18 - 17 - 22 - 14 - 29` and the `swapNodes()` function has to swap the two nodes with the keys 18, but instead I get these elements: `4 - 18 - 4 - 10 - 18 - 17 - 22 - 14 - 29`. I tried to initialize the list with the exact values as before "swapping" and then try to swap these two nodes and everything works as it should.

PS: I would appreciate if someone could help me to write the `swapNodes()` function with fewer lines but that's not a necessity at this moment.

```
typedef struct _node{
    int key;
    struct _node *next;
    struct _node *prev;
}node;

node* createNode(int key){
    node* a = (node*)malloc(sizeof(struct _node));
    a->key = key;
    a->next = NULL;
    a->prev = NULL;
    return a;
}

void printList(node* head){
    while (head != NULL){
        printf("%d", head->key);
        if(head->next != NULL) printf(" - ");
        head = head->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void fillList(node** head, int dim){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<dim; i++)
        listInsert(head, createNode(rand()%30));
}

//findes a node given an index, the indices start from 1
node** findNode(node** head, int index){
    int i;
    for(i=1; i<index; i++)
        head = &(*head)->next;
    if(head != NULL) return head;
    else return NULL;
}

void listInsert(node** head, node* node){
    if((*head) == NULL){
        (*head) = node;
        return;
    }
    node->next = (*head);
    (*head)->prev = node;
    (*head) = node;
}

int main(){
    node* list = NULL;
    fillList(&list, 10);
    int i, a, b;
    for(i=0; i<100; i++){
        printList(list);
        a = rand()%10 +1;
        b = rand()%10 +1;
        swapNodes(&list, *findNode(&list, a), *findNode(&list, b));
        printList(list);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

EDIT:

I managed to rewrite the `swapNodes()` function but this time executing the same lines in main I get a loop in the list for `i==15`, `a==4` and `b==2`. Again if I try to manualy swap any of the nodes the function works fine.

```
void swapNodes(node** head, node* a, node* b){
    node* aPrev = a->prev;
    node* aNext = a->next;
    node* bPrev = b->prev;
    node* bNext = b->next;
    if(a == b) return;
    if(a->prev == b || 
    (b->prev == NULL && a->next == NULL) || 
    (b->prev == NULL && b->next == a) || 
    a->next == NULL) return swapNodes(head, b, a);
    if(a->prev == NULL)
        (*head) = b;
    else if(b->prev == NULL)
        (*head) = a;

    if(a->next == b){
        if(aPrev != NULL) aPrev->next = b;
        b->prev = aPrev;
        b->next = a;
        bNext->prev = a;
        a->prev = b;
        a->next = bNext;
    }else{
        b->next = aNext;
        a->next = bNext;

        if(a->prev != NULL)
            aPrev->next = b;
        if(b->prev != NULL)
            bPrev->next = a;

        if(a->next != NULL)
            aNext->prev = b;
        if(bNext != NULL)
            bNext->prev = a;

        if(b != NULL)
            b->prev = aPrev;
        if(a != NULL)
            a->prev = bPrev;
    }
}
```

Comment: shouldn't the swap function swap only the keys in the node ?

Comment: I didn't look closely at your code, but the `swapNodes` function looks terribly convoluted to me. Are you sure the list creation work correctly?

Comment: Well I could swap only the keys but at this point I need to swap the nodes themselves. And what if in the future I decided to store more information in every node? I would have to rewrite a new swap function (like I would have to do with most of the other functions)

Comment: I know that the swap function is terribly written, but for now I would like to find what causes the bug. Also I have written at the end of my question about the function itself

Comment: @ggorlen I rewrote the function but the problems continue. I have updated the code

Comment: This is a bit easier to get a grip on, thanks. Are the problems you're having the same as before? If not, please show cases this is failing on. You might want to remove your original code and swap in the new code if you're certain it's better to keep the post focused. Here's another general hint/recommendation: If your goal is to swap two nodes, you can approach it like this: write a helper function to unlink a node. Write a helper function to insert a node. Now, the "swap nodes" function is trivial: call your unlink function for each node, then call the insert function for each node.

Comment: What is `nodoLista`?

Comment: @ggorlen Thanks for the suggestion, that could work since it's more "clear". I'm gonna try it

Comment: @gsamaras nevermind, I just forgot to "translate" it in english, sould be `node` (in general I write the code in italian)

Comment: Note: I haven't tried my above suggestion, so it might make it more complicated. But it's a general approach for cases when you're dealing with a lot of complexity in one function and can't seem to cut it down past 30 or 40 LOC with lots of messy pointers/conditionals to reason about. The problem with the suggestion is keeping  track of where the nodes were in the list after removal, which is why I'm backing off from the idea a bit.

Comment: @AntonisPetropoulos I remember when I wrote my code in Greek-lish when I first programmed. After a semester or two (by then writing clean English code), I wanted to reuse a method of minimum path finding I had implemented back in the days, and when I say the Greek-lish, it seemed like Chinese to me - I  rewrote the method from scratch. :) If you'd like, follow my suggestion. Moreover, I strongly advice you to edit your question, replacing the long swap method with your new one, since that's now not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the idea that @ggorlen gave me, I rewrote the `swapNodes()` function adding also some new ones and finally it works perfectly. To keep track of where the nodes were before extracting them, I created a `struct` containing the index returned from the `findIndex()` function and the node itself. I also changed the `findNode()` function so that it returns a variable of type `node*` and not `node**`. Sure it's not very efficient, but I'll make do.

```
typedef struct _extractedNode{
    struct _node* node;
    int index;
}extractedNode;

int findIndex(node* head, node* node){
    int i=1;
    node* temp = head;
    while(node != temp){
        temp = temp->next;
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}

extractedNode extractNode(node** head, node* node){
    extractedNode extracted;
    extracted.index = 0;
    if(node == NULL){
        printf("extractNode(): il nodo non esiste!\n");
        extracted.node = NULL;
        extracted.index = -1;
    }else{
        node* prev = node->prev;
        node* next = node->next;
        if(prev == NULL){
            (*head) = next;
            extracted.index = 1;
        }
        if(extracted.index != 1)
            extracted.index = findIndex(*head, node);
        if(prev != NULL)
            prev->next = next;
        if(next != NULL)
            next->prev = prev;
        node->next = NULL;
        node->prev = NULL;
        extracted.node = node;
    }
    return extracted;
}

void listInsertAsIndex(node** head, int index, node* node){
    if(index <= 0) return;
    if(index == 1) return listInsert(head, node);
    else{
        node* prev = findNode(*head, index-1);
        node* next = prev->next;
        prev->next = node;
        node->prev = prev;
        if(next != NULL){
            node->next = next;
            next->prev = node;
        }
    }
}

void swapNodes(node** head, node* a, node* b){
    if(a == b) return;
    extractedNode aX, bX;
    if(a->prev == NULL && a->next == b){
        aX = extractNode(head, a);
        listInsertAsIndex(head, 2, aX.node);
    }else if(b->prev == NULL && b->next == a){
        bX = extractNode(head, b);
        listInsertAsIndex(head, 2, bX.node);
    }else if(a->next == b){
        aX = extractNode(head, a);
        listInsertAsIndex(head, aX.index +1, aX.node);
    }else if(b->next == a){
        bX = extractNode(head, b);
        listInsertAsIndex(head, bX.index +1, bX.node);
    }else{
        aX = extractNode(head, a);
        bX = extractNode(head, b);
        if(aX.index < bX.index){
            listInsertAsIndex(head, aX.index, bX.node);
            listInsertAsIndex(head, bX.index +1, aX.node);
        }else{
            listInsertAsIndex(head, bX.index, aX.node);
            listInsertAsIndex(head, aX.index, bX.node);
        }
    }
}
```